# How to express 80^2/3 as a product of powers of prime numbers

Tags: exponentiation, prime-factorization

So the given was: $(80)^\frac23(25)^\frac32$ and I was told to simplify and express as a product of powers of prime numbers.

Now I'm not very familiar with this product of powers of prime numbers so correct me if I'm wrong but what I did first was simplify $(25)^\frac32$ to $125$ and then (presumably) to express it as a product of powers of prime numbers, I divided it to a Prime number that was most likely a factor which was $5$ and ended up with $5\cdot5\cdot5$ or $5^3$ (again correct me if I'm wrong) so now we have
$$(80)^\frac23\cdot5^3$$
we can't simplify $(80)^\frac23$ because $\sqrt[3]{6400}$ doesn't have a simple answer so what I did was express $80$ as a product of powers of prime numbers which became $2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot5$ or simply $2^4\cdot5$ the final answer being: $$(2^4\cdot5)^\frac23\cdot5^3$$

Is this the simplest it can get? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: This question is not well-posed (I mean whoever asked you to show this did not give you a well-posed question).  What does it mean to write a non-integer as a product of powers of primes.  For example, $\sqrt 2 = p^{\log_p \sqrt{2}}$ for any $p$, so this product is not unique (unless i misunderstand the question).  You are correct that $(2^4 \cdot 5)^{2/3} \cdot 5^3$ is the quantity you're trying to simplify, but notice that $80 = 8 \cdot 10$, so $80^{2/3} = 8^{2/3} \cdot 10^{2/3} = 4 \cdot 10^{2/3}$.

Comment: Another vote for "not a good question."

Comment: I wouldn't be asking here if it was just a simple question xD
Hence why I'm asking here since I can't make sense of the question myself @bof I can provide a picture of the exact question on paper for clarification

Comment: Why isn't this simple? The powers don't have to be integers, do they?

Comment: simple in the sense that it's easy to do i.e. don't have to be asked on stack exchange.

Comment: I suppose that the desired answer is $5^{11/3}\cdot2^{8/3}$  I'm with @JohnDouma.  Why isn't this simple?

Comment: @saulspatz can you explain in further detail how did you get to that answer (not in comments ofc)? for future reference and a clear explanation for my very confused brain xD

Comment: @bof Outlandish interpretation?  Or outlandish manners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$80^{2/3}\cdot25^{3/2}=(2^4\cdot5)^{2/3}\cdot(5^2)^{3/2}=(2^4)^{2/3}\cdot5^{2/3}\cdot5^3=2^{8/3}\cdot5^{11/3}$$

Comment: how did $25^\frac32$ not become 125? can you explain more in detail? xd

Comment: $5^3=125,$ but since powers of primes are requested, it's easier to leave it as $5^3.$

Comment: Ah thanks I got it now, I'll be putting this as the answer, and for future reference I will update with the correct answer (and question) once my teacher clarifies everything xP

Answer (score 1):

Weird way of putting it but:

$80$ can be expressed in terms of prime factorization as $2^4\cdot5$.  And $25$ as $5^2$

So $(80)^{\frac 23}\cdot(25)^{\frac 32}= $

$(2^4\cdot 5)^{\frac 23}\cdot (5^2)^{\frac 32} = $

$(2^{4\cdot \frac 23}\cdot 5^{\frac 23})\cdot(5^{2\cdot\frac 32})=$

$2^{\frac 83}\cdot 5^{\frac 23}\cdot 5^3=$

$2^{\frac 83}\cdot 5^{\frac 23 + 3}=$

$2^{\frac 83}\cdot 5^{\frac {11}3}$

Now I have no idea why anyone would *want* to express it that way....

===

With experience and comfort so things become clearer and apparent.

$25^{\frac 12} = 5$ and $8^{\frac 13} = 2$ so

$(80)^{\frac 23}\cdot (25)^{\frac 32} =$

$(2^2\cdot 10^{\frac 23})\cdot (5^3) = $

$2^2\cdot 2^{\frac 23}\cdot 5^{\frac 23}\cdot 5^3 = $

$2^{2 + \frac 23}5^{3 + \frac 23}=$

$2^{\frac 83}5^{\frac {11}3}$.

That's perhaps a little slicker but not as obvious or as illustrative to learn by.